# cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG

Tags: python, opencv

I've found [a tutorial about Kalman filters](https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/~maucher/Python/ComputerVision/html/Tracking.html), it also contains background subtraction step as preprocessing:

```
bgs = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(history,nGauss,bgThresh,noise)
```

I can't find it in Python OpenCV 4.2, only cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 and it is insufficient because I can't find parameters for the proper work of this algorithm.
I see in the documentation that there is [cv::bgsegm::BackgroundSubtractorMOG Class](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/da7/classcv_1_1bgsegm_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG.html) for C++. Does it mean this class is available for Python? If yes, how?
I tried these:

```
bgs = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
bgs = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
bgs = cv2.bgsegm.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

Comment: how about `help( cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG )` in Python code. OR use IDE which can gives information about parameters when you write function's name.

Comment: @furas `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'` if I use `help( cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG )`, also I use the standard import: `import cv2` - nothing special

Comment: but it has `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`

Comment: BTW: `cv2` keeps images as `numpy array` and some operations can be done in different way then in C/C++ - for example normal substraction `diff = image1 - image2` - and if you would know how exactly works `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` then probably  you would do this using numpy functions.